# ASP.net/IIS, action after release, IISReset/AppPool Recycle

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a problem with a server. After a release(or simply replacing web.config), my site take more than 120sec to return and I got an error (timeout).

- I could try to call any pages I got the same error.
- I try to call non-existing page, I got the same error (2mins and webseal return an error, the server did not respond instead of showing the error for a page not found/exist.)
- After 5 to 10 minutes, the page is ok.
- I have the same problem for sub-directory ( like if pages are ok in the main directory, in a subdirectory I got the error)
- IISreset or appPool Recycle doesn't recause the problem.
- I used and old version of the code, and I have the same problem.
- The code working on my development environment.
- if the code work once (show the page), he will always work( until I
  re-graduate, with same or new code)

Comment: Sounds like slow start up, probably because the disk/io subsystem on a tyical server is much, much slower than on a workstation. Try precompiling the markup or reviewing what is happening in global asax early app start events.

Comment: Can you post the IIS logs starting with when IIS is restarted?

Comment: Only for this "if the code work once (show the page), he will always work" - that is because your site is already in the cache...

Comment: why iisreset or a recycle doesn't clean the cache?